# Different possible program outputs?

Tags: c, pthreads

From the code below, is the output answer only `8`? What other possible outputs could there be (explanations would be great)?

```
int i = 0;
void *doit(void *vargp) {
   i = i + 5;
}
int main() {
   pthread_t tid;
   pthread_create(&tid, NULL, doit, NULL);
   i = i + 3;
   pthread_join(tid, NULL);
   printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

Comment: Have you tested it?

Comment: Since your program has non-readonly, non-atomic, unsynchronized access to an object from multiple threads, the behavior is undefined. Therefore, the program is entirely meaningless. There need not be *any* output from the program, and if there is, it is perfectly permissible for the output to be "elephant".

Comment: @EOF this is one of the practice problems. Based on the given code, will the possible output be either 3 or 8 ?

Comment: @ssss Then your instructor doesn't know C. The range of possible outputs is unrestricted.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not using mutexes, you may run into undefined behaviour where both the main thread and the doit thread see i = 0 and then i is set to 5 or 3.

A fix might be:

```
int i = 0;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER; // this is since the mutex is a global variable. 

void *doit(void *vargp) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
    i = i + 5;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);
}

int main() {
    pthread_t tid;
    int *ptr = &i;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, doit, NULL);

    pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
    i = i + 3;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);

    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    printf("%d",i);
}
```

Comment: so from the original problem the answer could both 3,5, and 8 ?

Comment: @ssss: That's the minimum set of answers — there could be various forms of garbage too, depending...